# Why does not read JSON file?

Tags: java, json, dictionary, iterator, filereader

This code should read JSON file which is one element array, and then it should read all elements of that array, but I get a result just one row and it looks something like this:

```
reviews[{"sourceId":"890cdd7974cdf8aabe6e9051f5a87303bdb933ae","logoHref":null,"reviewerId":null,"reviewCreatedOnTime":161157...
```

Here is the code to read file:

```
FileReader read=new FileReader("C:\\Users\\User\\eclipse-workspace\\Task\\files\\reviews.json");
    JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
    Object obj=parser.parse(read);
    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
    jsonObject=(JSONObject) obj;
    
    JSONArray reviews = new JSONArray();
    reviews=(JSONArray) jsonObject.get("reviews");
    
    Iterator<Map.Entry> itr1 = jsonObject.entrySet().iterator();
    while (itr1.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = itr1.next();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " " + pair.getValue());
    }
//json file
{
"reviews":[
  {
    "id": 2097047,
    "reviewId": "93f131be27dc1122bb7ef0048ad10e4f",
    "reviewFullText": "5 star review",
    "reviewText": "5 star review",
    "numLikes": 0,
    "numComments": 0,
    "numShares": 0,
    "rating": 5,
    "reviewCreatedOn": "2 months ago",
    "reviewCreatedOnDate": "2021-01-25T13:00:35+00:00",
    "reviewCreatedOnTime": 1611579635,
    "reviewerId": null,
    "reviewerUrl": null,
    "reviewerName": "Reviewer #20",
    "reviewerEmail": null,
    "sourceType": "custom",
    "isVerified": false,
    "source": "custom",
    "sourceName": "1-20 Reviews",
    "sourceId": "890cdd7974cdf8aabe6e9051f5a87303bdb933ae",
    "tags": [],
    "href": null,
    "logoHref": null,
    "photos": []
  },
```

Comment: Have you done any [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? What did you find?

Comment: `reviews[{ ...` is not valid JSON. What does the content of the file look like?

Comment: Your code can't produce output you showing. Can you add real output? Also add example of input.

Comment: here is json :``` {
"reviews":[
  {
    "id": 2097047,
    "reviewId": "93f131be27dc1122bb7ef0048ad10e4f",
    "reviewFullText": "5 star review",
    "reviewText": "5 star review",
    "numLikes": 0,
    "numComments": 0,

Comment: I added json file, can u see it?

Comment: Please add the actual output of your program

Comment: this is output:```reviews [{"sourceId":"890cdd7974cdf8aabe6e9051f5a87303bdb933ae","logoHref":null...and then start json data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is the fact that you're not taking the `reviews` object, but instead still referencing the main json object.

```
Iterator<Map.Entry> itr1 = jsonObject.entrySet().iterator();
```

should change the `jsonObject` to `reviews`, but at the same time, giving the fact that it's a `JSONArray`, since you said that it will only be a single element in the array, you can just take the first element from the array, i.e. `.get(0)`

Then your code would change as follows:

```
Iterator<Entry> itr1 = ((JSONObject)reviews.get(0)).entrySet().iterator();
while (itr1.hasNext()) {
  Map.Entry pair = itr1.next();
  System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " " + pair.getValue());
}
```

And your output is what you expected:

```
sourceId 890cdd7974cdf8aabe6e9051f5a87303bdb933ae
logoHref null
reviewerId null
reviewCreatedOnTime 1611579635
isVerified false
rating 5
reviewerUrl null
reviewFullText 5 star review
source custom
numLikes 0
reviewCreatedOnDate 2021-01-25T13:00:35+00:00
photos []
tags []
numComments 0
reviewerName Reviewer #20
sourceType custom
reviewerEmail null
numShares 0
id 2097047
sourceName 1-20 Reviews
href null
reviewId 93f131be27dc1122bb7ef0048ad10e4f
reviewCreatedOn 2 months ago
reviewText 5 star review
```

If you want to process *all* reviews and read each review as a map, you can do as follows:

```
    FileReader read = new FileReader(
        "C:\\Users\\User\\eclipse-workspace\\Task\\files\\reviews.json");
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = parser.parse(read);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

    JSONArray reviews = new JSONArray();
    reviews = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("reviews");

    Iterator<Entry> itr1 = reviews.iterator();
    while (itr1.hasNext()) {

      Iterator<Entry> itr2 = ((JSONObject) itr1.next()).entrySet().iterator();
      while (itr2.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = itr2.next();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " " + pair.getValue());
      }
    }
```

Side note: I would encourage you use a bit more easy approach with well built libraries such as `jackson` or `gson` instead of manipulating this way the data.

Comment: Yes you are right, I can use library but the task was to solve it without using library